# php ?: Operator multiple change

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to have what this would output:

```
if ($user->newsletter == 1) { 
    echo 'YES'; }
else {
    echo 'NO'; }
```

What I have:

```
echo $user->newsletter == 0 ?: 'YES' ?: 'NO';
```

This outputs `YES` where it should be `YES`, so this is okay,
but it outputs `1` where it should be `NO`.

Is there a way how to write this?

Comment: Simply `echo ($user->newsletter == 1) ? 'YES' : 'NO';`.... no need to try nesting ternaries at all

Comment: `?:` is called the "Elvis operator", it returns single value if former was falsy. Remember that in PHP it's counter-intuitive as it's left-associative, so `$x ?: $y ?: $z` does not mean `$x ?: ($y ?: $z)` but `($x ?: $y) ?: $z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit odd. This is how you typically use the ternary operator:

```
echo ($user->newsletter == 1) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

---

As of PHP 5.3 there is a new way to use the ternary operator:

```
$foo = $foo ?: $bar;
// which is equivalent to
$foo = $foo ? $foo : $bar;
```

This short hand is referred to as the *Elvis operator*.

In your case you can not use this shorthand as you want to transform `0` or `1` into `'Yes'` or `'No'`.